Can a DisplayPort be restarted in Windows?
I have three monitors plugged in to my Intel UHD Graphics 750 board. The main monitor is 4K plugged into HDMI, one HD monitor on DVI and another HD monitor on the DisplayPort (using an DisplayPort <-> HDMI cable).
My issue is that when my Windows PC auto-locks or 'powers down' after the timeout (sometimes) the DisplayPort monitor will not come back up after I awaken the PC. It just says "no signal". It seems to be at the PC end, because power cycling the monitor, unplugging/re-plugging the cables etc, does nothing. The only way I can get the monitor back up is to restart the machine. Often this is inconvenient to say the least.
I've tried the Ctrl+Shift+Win+B trick, I've tried disabling / enabling the Display Adapter. Does anyone know of any other ways I might give the DisplayPort a kick-in-the-proverbial to wake it up, without having to reboot?

The problem is your displayport to hdmi converter. If you replace it with just a dp to hdmi cable, it should work.

It is just a cable - no converter.

I'm not sure this is the solution yet - I need to give it some "wait-and-see" time - but the power brick on the "problem" monitor just completely died. I'll have to see how it goes, but it may be that a slowly dying power brick was the ultimate cause of the problem.
